# Pixel-precise rendering of bitmaps on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

My application shows bitmaps (map tiles) of fixed width and length. They cover the whole screen and I scroll the map pixel by pixel. 
I have two versions of the app, 8.0 Silverlight (container is Canvas and map tiles are Images, and 8.1 Store (using Win2d library, but also tested XAML).

When I run 8.0 app version on Lumia 820 (480x800), ScaleFactor is 100, everything is crisp and screen is perfectly covered. However, when I run it in 720p emulator, or when I run 8.1 version on Lumia (RawPixelPerViewPixel is > 1.0, 1.2 I think) or in any emulator, there are issues.

Images are blurry - I understood apps are scaled and it seems there is nothing I can do about it, but bigger problem of my app it that as I scroll the map, the tiles do not cover the main panel, most of the time there is some space between them I can see panel background (red color in the screenshot), only every 5th map scroll (for RawPixelPerViewPixel = 1.2) the tiles are perfectly adjacent to each other and background is completely painted over.

I use integers for positioning tiles on the screen, so for example for tiles 240x320 I put first at 0,0 the next to 240,0 etc. How can I get rid of the spacings between the tiles? Should I switch from int to float for coordinates and somehow use ScaleFactor to calculate positions more precisely? Thank you.

[image: 8.1 emulator screenshot]

Comment: There are two attributes for the WPF views that generally resolve that kind of problem, one is SnapsToDevicePixels="True" and the other is UseLayoutRounding="True". I used them once so I don't remember exactly how they work but if you play with them a little you should be able to resolve your problem

Comment: Sure, you are seeing the effects of automatic rescaling.  For Phone it is 100, 140 or 180%, depending on the screen resolution.  That doesn't explain the problem with the tiles, multiplying 240 pixels by 1.4 or 1.8 produces a integral number.  But if you use (0, 0) and (239, 0) then you are certainly doing it wrong, that's off by 1.  We can't see your code.  Read [the backgrounder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for hints.

Comment: @Hans Passant Hi, sorry 239,0 was mistake, of course it is 240,0. I put together a simple app that just put 2 map tiles to canvas and every time a pointer is pressed, it shifts images to the left by 1 pixel. The effect is reproducible. [https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=4805B614011347AB&resid=4805B614011347AB!554&authkey=AMlRX3lCya7qN0E]

Comment: XAML: `<Canvas Background="Red" x:Name="canvas">
        <Image Source="world_0_0.png" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"/>
        <Image Source="world_240_0.png" Canvas.Left="240" Canvas.Top="0"/>
    </Canvas>` Code: `void canvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Image i in canvas.Children.OfType<Image>()) {
                Canvas.SetLeft(i, Canvas.GetLeft(i) - 1);
            }
        }`

Comment: I just found out that when I shift images not by 1 pixel but by `1.0 / RawPixelsPerViewPixel`, there are never any visual artefacts during scrolling. So it really seems that I have to use scaling factor in calculations of images coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

So I just found out that in order to avoid those subpixel artefact lines, which is the panel (canvas in my case) showing through subpixel spaces between rendered bitmaps, bitmap on-screen coordinates have to be multiples of (1.0 / RawPixelsPerViewPixel).